# Converting heart beat rate to animate pulsing graphic

Tags: math, lua, heartrate

My maths is terrible. The graphic must pulse synced to HR. The pulsing is controlled by an opacity value that maxes out at 100=fully opaque and starts at 0=transparent. So i need to ramp up to 100 in fractions and back down again and repeat all using a function that gets called once a millisecond.

E.g.
I have bpm as 50
Per second is 60/50=1.2
Per millisecond as 1.2/1000=0.0012
Then 100 (the max opaque value)/0.0012 = 83,333 steps to get to 100 in increments of 0.0012 ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a function that gets called once a millisecond

No way!

I suggest calling your function much, much slower and ramping the transparency with larger increments - the visual effect will be identical.

Suggest calling your function 10 times per second.